# How to merge columns containing list values when some column list values are emptly?

Tags: python, list, pandas, array-merge

I want to merge columns from data frames in such a way:

```
list_A      list_B       
A, T, G     G, C        
            B, K         
C, L, AG    L, AG, K     
F, K
```

The output should be:

```
list_A      list_B       list_A&B
A, T, G     G, C         A, T, G, C
            B, K         B, K
C, L, AG    L, AG, K     C, L, AG, K
F, K                     F, K
```

**I did:**

`df['list_A&B'] = df['list_A'].astype(list) + ', ' + df['list_B'].astype(list)`

And, I am getting:

```
     list_A    list_B            list_A&B
0   A, T, G      G, C       A, T, G, G, C
1       NaN      B, K                 NaN
2  C, L, AG  L, AG, K  C, L, AG, L, AG, K
3      F, K       NaN                 NaN
```

**Here the union of the list is a problem when one of the list is empty. But, why?**

**I then tried unionizing as string but now the added nan cannot be dropped:**
`df['list_A&B'] = df['list_A'].astype(str) + ', ' + df['list_B'].astype(str)`

which gives:

```
     list_A    list_B            list_A&B
0   A, T, G      G, C       A, T, G, G, C
1       NaN      B, K           nan, B, K
2  C, L, AG  L, AG, K  C, L, AG, L, AG, K
3      F, K       NaN           F, K, nan
```

With this output, I am having difficulty removing 'nan' since they are reported as strings and dropna() and fillna() don't work with it.

Any suggestions !
- K

Comment: What are the actual values in your columns?  Are they just strings like `"A, T, G"`?  What are the empty values?  Are they empty strings?  Can you provide a self-contained example with sample data (i.e., the code to generate your sample DataFrame)?

Comment: The actual values in the columns are list of letter or strings. The column are tab separated and any empty values in the column are empty strings `i.e the empty row/columns cells are just tab jumps without any white space to represent the empty value/list.` This dataframe was generated by joining two dataframe using pandas merge function, where the empty values are (NaN). The keys used to merge isn't quite relevant (I think) and not shown.

Comment: I don't see any lists in your data.  If there were lists, I'd expect the value to be, e.g, `["A", "T", "G"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like those are simply string values going by my interpretation of the data you've provided so far.

***Steps:***

Concatenate them row-wise using [`str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)with `sep=','` and `na_rep=''` which takes care of the `NaN` values interspersed with the other string chars by treating it as an empty char.

Then, remove unwanted whitespaces present among them and also eliminate empty strings using `filter(None,...)` after having taken the unique elements of the list using `set`.

Finally, join the resulting list to make it a string representation of the list but excluding the brackets.

```
df['list_A&B'] = df['list_A'].str.cat(df['list_B'], ',','') \
                  .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(filter(None, set(re.sub(r"\s+", "", x) \
                  .split(','))))))

df                  # df.fillna('') to get back your desired output
```

[image]

---

Starting `DF` used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'list_A': ['A, T, G', np.NaN, 'C, L, AG ', 'F, K'], 
                   'list_B': ['G, C', 'B, K', 'L, AG, K', np.NaN]})
df
```

[image]